# How to Join Multi Datatable(DataColumn) into One but separete Column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following 3 query statements:

```
sSQLSting1 = "SELECT * From Column1"
sSQLSting2 = "SELECT * From Column2"
sSQLSting3 = "SELECT * From Column3"
```

[image]

**Edit:** Column1 is the name of table1 but it's just a column.

I want to join them all into different columns of a new Datatable but when tried with: 
`sSQLSting1 & " Union " & sSQLSting2 & " Union " & sSQLSting3` , but the list returns only a column.

My desire result is to create a table that includes all of the above columns, so my question is: 
can I do this with just one query statement or do I have to iterate and add data for each column? (i'm using c#).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Give example data and desired results. It is totally unclear. You have a **table** called **Column1**? What columns does that contain?

Comment: You have a table called Column1?   Your naming convention is a little confusing.   Perhaps a small data sample and desired results would be a better visual

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I have updated the post!

Comment: OK you have given example results but not the source data that goes along with it. Specifically how are rows in the tables mapped to each other? This is a join not a union but you need something to join on

Comment: Hi, I want to add them respectively according to row position, row1 in column1 and row1 in column2 ... same row in new table. (they are not related to each other)

Comment: @TheGridLock Is there a column that can be used to determine the sequence/row number ?   SQL Server has unordered sets.  This means that without a specifice Order By, there is no GTD of the order.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, no, they're all strings, I just want to put them in that order in the new table

Comment: If you're using c# why does your code taste like VB.NET?

Comment: @Caius Jard Hi, I am looking for a sample file and I see vb so i post here, I can use both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help a bit

Again, there is NO GTD of the proper sequence.  Also this assumes same number of rows in each table

**Example**

```
Select Col1 = A.SomeColumn
      ,Col2 = B.SomeColumn
      ,Col3 = C.SomeColumn
 From ( Select SomeColumn,RN=row_number() over (order by SomeColumn ) from Column1 ) A
 Join ( Select SomeColumn,RN=row_number() over (order by SomeColumn ) from Column2 ) B on A.RN=B.RN
 Join ( Select SomeColumn,RN=row_number() over (order by SomeColumn ) from Column3 ) C on A.RN=C.RN
```

**EDIT another option is a PIVOT**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select Value=SomeColumn,Col=1,RN=row_number() over (order by SomeColumn ) from Column1
        Union All
        Select Value=SomeColumn,Col=2,RN=row_number() over (order by SomeColumn ) from Column2
        Union All
        Select Value=SomeColumn,Col=3,RN=row_number() over (order by SomeColumn ) from Column3
       ) src
 Pivot (max(value) for Col in ([1],[2],[3]) ) pvt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try your query, which is quite confusing for me.

Comment: @TheGridLock Give it a shot.  The first one is using a row_number()  to generate a common key to join on.  The second one is using row_number()  as the GROUP BY.

Comment: @TheGridLock The real problem here is your design.  You have 3 tables with one column each.   There is no real way to associate a cell value with the next.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying me! I understood the problem.

Comment: @TheGridLock Always happy to help

Answer (score 1):

This would probably be simplest to do on the client side:

```
for(int x = 1; x < dts.Length; x++){
  dts[0].Columns.Add(dts[x].Columns[0].ColumnName);

  for(int y = 0; y <  dts[x].Rows.Count; y++)
    dts[0].Rows[y][x] = dts[x].Rows[y][0];

}
```

It'll handle any number of datatables in an array (called dts) - change Length to Coubt if it's a list etc

All columns names must be unique (yours are) - Logic can be added to append something to the name to make it unique

All data is copied into the first table in the array

If your columns are other than string you can add the type of the new column added to dts[0] by taking the type of dts[x].Columns[0]